# node.js & express: internal redirect for request inside of router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using current express 4 and node.js 6.x. In my web application I need to do an internal redirect (i.e. redirect from one route handler to another, without sending a redirect to the client). This works within toplevel express or within the same router, but not if the source request is located in a Router.

Please see the following minimal working example:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = module.exports.app = express();
const router = new express.Router();

app.use("/myrouter", router);

// not working
router.get("/test", (req, res, next) => {
  req.url = "/toplevel";
  next();
});

// working
app.get("/test", (req, res, next) => {
    req.url = "/toplevel";
    next();
});

// debug output
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`request to ${req.url}`);
  next();
});

app.get("/toplevel", (req, res) => {
  res.end("toplevel");
});

app.listen(8000);
```

If I open "http://localhost:8000/test", I get the correct output "toplevel", and the debug output prints "request to /toplevel". Unfortunately it doesn't work for "http://localhost:8000/myrouter/test". The debug output prints "request to /myrouter/toplevel" and I get the result of the default express 404 handler.

Is there any may to redirect the request from "/myrouter/test" to "/toplevel" without redirecting the client (i.e. `res.redirect()`)?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. It looks like Express treats a router as a standalone app, and rewriting `req.url` is always done within the context of that app (that is, Express appends the mount path, in this case `/myrouter`, to `req.url` internally if you change it).

Comment: Try to change `req.originalUrl`

Comment: @ponury-kostek I tried that as well, didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Did you find a way to do the internal redirect?